# How to programatically run a .exe file while the computer is booting up? c#

Tags: c#, windows, exe, boot

Is it possible to programatically (c#) run a .exe file while the computer is booting up? I need the .exe to run while the computer is booting up so that it will not allow the user to complete any actions until the processor usage is below a certain point. I have looked on the internet and on stack overflow and haven't had any luck. Any suggestions or just a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Are you writing a virus or something?

Comment: Like, during POST?  Before the OS is loaded?  Before the shell is loaded?  What stage in the bootup process?

Comment: @MikeChristensen Not quite sure where in the bootup process. After the OS or Shell would both be fine.

Comment: You can put it in your registry entry for Run or RunOnce. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @trueamerican420 Are you suuuuuure?

Comment: I'm less concerned about how you would run an exe file on startup ("while the computer is booting up" would be difficult, just running it when you log in is easy), and more concerned, how would you "not allow the user to complete any actions"?

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll pass on answering this one for you.  Sorry.  I don't see any good coming from this question.

Comment: Basically the .exe would just pop up a little screen to tell them to hold on until the .cpu usage was lower so that it doesn't crash. The main problem is that we are running numerous remote connections on one computer

Comment: Why can't you write a program to start the remote connections only when you feel the system has become stable, and start at a safe pace?

Comment: You should have added the situation in your question. More info when you ask = more ideas you get.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the full path for the EXE your registry entry for Run or RunOnce. See here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376977(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

A possible option is that you built it as a *windows service* and set it to *start automatically*. That can monitor your desired things at start up.